# proper teardown of a WebRTC RTCPeerConnection

Tags: webrtc, rtcpeerconnection, mediastreamtrack

I tried to do a simple WebRTC p2p video chat browser app. I setup a signal server and have two peers doing all the `SDP` and `ICE` handshakes. Some of my code snippet:

```
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
 ...
}
pc.ontrack(event) =>{
  if (event.track.kind === 'video') {
    // add the stream as the srcObject of a video tag
  }
  event.streams[0].onremovetrack = (e) => {
    // want to remove the stream from the video tag
  }
}
```

When a peer is done I do the following:

```
pc.stop();
```

I simply just close the RTCPeerConnection. But I don't see the `onremovetrack` being triggered on the other peer.

What is the proper way to shutdown a peer so that the other peer can be notified and `onremovetrack` triggered?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use the `RTCPeerConnection.removeTrack()` method, it will fire the `MediaStream.onremovetrack` event at the other end.

To get the tracks of the connection use the `RTCPeerConnection.getSenders()` method.

> The RTCPeerConnection method getSenders() returns an array of
> RTCRtpSender objects, each of which represents the RTP sender
> responsible for transmitting one track's data.

**Example**

```
let senders = pc.getSenders()

senders.forEach((sender) => {
  pc.removeTrack(sender)
})
```

This will remove all the tracks from the connection. There's an experimental method to completely close the connection, `RTCPeerConnection.close()`, check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/close#browser_compatibility). Use it after the tracks removed, so you will get the `onremovetrack` events:

```
pc.close()
```

> Calling this method terminates the RTCPeerConnection's ICE agent,
> ending any ongoing ICE processing and any active streams.

**Alternative**

The other way is to immediately call the `close()` method and listen to the `RTCPeerConnection.onconnectionstatechange` event at the other end, check the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onconnectionstatechange#example).

**More information**

- [`getSenders()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getSenders) method
- [`removeTrack()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/removeTrack) method
- [`onremovetrack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/removetrack_event) event handler
- [`close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/close) method
- [`onconnectionstatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onconnectionstatechange) event handler